# Binding UserControl in datatemplate

Tags: wpf, binding

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:ViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" common:CustomAttachedProperties.IsAccessKeyScope="True">
            <userControl:MyBanner DockPanel.Dock="Left" x:Name="UserBanner" EmergencyProtocolVisible="False" />
            <userControl:PageSummary DockPanel.Dock="Top" x:Name="_adminSummaryWithFooter"/>
            <userControl:Footer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="_myFooter" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type userControl:PageSummary}}, Path=.}">
                <userControl:Footer.InnerContent>
                    <StackPanel Background="Red" Height="300px" Width="500px">

                    </StackPanel>
                </userControl:Footer.InnerContent>
            </userControl:Footer>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I need to use Viewmodel Icommand inside Footer element. Cannnot find element if I try this `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type userControl:PageSummary}}, Path=.}`. Also I have tried using `ElementName`, with name specified in the other control.

Image using Scoop, need to get reference of AdminSummary object into Footer:
[image: Image using Scoop, need to get reference of AdminSummary object into Footer]

Please advice

Comment: in your sample `Footer` and `PageSummary` should have the same DataContext (inherited from Parent) without any special manipulations like cross-binding

Comment: Yes in theory it shoud have same DataContext but it is not. There is no DataContext set for Footer user control and hence I want to pass the parent dataContext to the footer using XAML.

Comment: As ASh already mentioned, without any additional code, you should have the same datacontext, if you don't touch that property on your footer. If it's not the same, then is it possible, that one of your usercontrols overwrites it's own Datacontext?

Comment: Also, it would be great, if you can show us, where and how you want to use you Command Binding